# Заменить первое подходящее значение в строке в C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет.

Есть строка: `1,2,3~111,32,0~2039,123,23~0,0,0~0,0,0~0,0,0~23,0,0...`, также есть значение -  `1,2,3`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы на это значение изменилось только первая `0,0,0` в строке.

Как можно такое сделать?

В интернете нахожу только `String.Replace`, но он заменяет все `0,0,0`, а мне нужно только первое вхождение.

Кол-во чисел и сами числа случайные, в строке перед первым `0,0,0` может быть сколько угодно знаков.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Топорный вариант:

```
string s = "1,2,3~111,32,0~2039,123,23~0,0,0~0,0,0~0,0,0~23,0,0";
string target = "1,2,3";     // Подстрока, которую заменяем
string replaceTo = "0,0,0";  // Подстрока, на которую заменяем
int IndexFirst = s.IndexOf(target);
s = s.Remove(IndexFirst, target.Length).Insert(IndexFirst, replaceTo);
```

Менее топорный:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("0,0,0");
s = reg.Replace(s, "1,2,3", 1);
```

Comment: Хмм, а target и replaceTo не наоборот ли?

Comment: @Mortmael target - то, что мы заменяем, replaceTo - на что. Попробуйте для начала, дальше поймете наоборот или нет. Поэтому мы сначала удаляем по позиции первого вхождения target кусок строки длинной target, а затем на это место вставляем replaceTo

Comment: А, я вас понял. Значение самих строк... Ну смените их:)